# How can I input http request parameters (headers, etc) into a request within a function?

Tags: http, python-requests, arguments, keyword-argument

Say I have a function that takes some *args (or **kwargs??) for a http request and I want to input different arguments each time the function is called - something like:

```
def make_some_request(self, *args)
    response = requests.get(*args)
    return response
```

where `*args` might be e.g. url, headers and parameters in one case and url and timeout in another case. How can this be formatted to get the request to look like

```
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=parameters)
```

on the first function call and

```
response = requests.get(url, timeout=timeout)
```

on the second function call?

I wondered if this was possible using *args or **kwargs but the format doesn't seem quite right with either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `**kwargs`:

```
class Client:
    def make_some_request(self, *args, **kwargs)
        response = requests.get(*args, **kwargs)
        return response

client = Client()
client.make_some_request("https://domain.tld/path?param=value", timeout=...)
client.make_some_request("https://domain.tld/path?param=value", headers=..., params=...)
```

`*args` will take care of passing the positional argument (the URL), whereas the named arguments (`timeout`, `headers`, `params`) will be passed to `requests.get` by `**kwargs`.

Comment: So this would work without me knowing that the first one is a timeout and the second is headers? e.g. I can put the **kwarg as timeout=timeout1, not just the timeout1 part?

Comment: @JJH I'm sorry, I don't understand that at all. Can you perhaps add an example of what you want to do to your original post?

Comment: No worries, I've sorted it - thanks for your help